# Next.js error "Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollTo')"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, scrollto

While making a portfolio website with Next.js, this is some sort of scrolling error that I'm getting from `.next` folder in my project folder.

Whenever I'm trying to get the mobile responsive view of the website this is the error I'm facing

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollTo')
```

This is the location of the error file

```
.next\static\chunks\pages\index.js (14:16) @ scroll
```

This is the code in that location

```
function _arrayLikeToArray(arr, len) {
  if (len == null || len > arr.length) len = arr.length;

  for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(len); i < len; i++) {
    arr2[i] = arr[i];
  }

  return arr2;
}
```

This is the snapshot of the error

[image]

I can run the website locally even when the error is showing. Is it gonna be a buggy thing if I deploy it?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Runtime is on browser, use `window.scrollTo` instead.

Comment: It has worked. Thank you.

Comment: Every time I reopen the app locally, it comes back with the same error. Again it's an error from the  `.next` folder, same location, same code block.

Comment: Hey, I put an answer down below to explain that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You've got this error on `Runtime` and it is on browser**

Since `node` is not available on the browser (only on node), you will need to use `window.scrollTo` instead

To completely remove it from the error logs, do a rebuilt so your `.next` will be wipe out and take the latest changes.

Comment: Is it possible to update my next from the integrated terminal?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Just “npm run build” will clear the old .next folder content